# How to connect a fully functioning iOS app to a new Firebase project

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, xcode8

I have an existing fully functioning app that connects to a Firebase project named "AppNameV1". I now want to set up separate Dev, Test, and Prod environments, so I created a new  Firebase project called "AppNameDev". I followed the instructions to add an iOS app to my Firebase project "AppNameDev", and downloaded the GoogleService-Info.plist file, and added it to my iOS project in Xcode. When I run the app in Xcode, I get the following error:

```
[Firebase/Database][I-RDB034005] Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server.  Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly
```

Comment: do you have separate package names for dev, test, and prod environments?

Comment: No, I don't. Where is the package name set up? Is that done within Firebase or Xcode?

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new iOS project in Firebase, it asks for your app's Bundle ID. It's not possible to register multiple apps with the same Bundle ID.
You should change your Bundle ID in Xcode. open your project file in Xcode, select your target, and change Bundle ID. It should be the same as the Bundle ID that you use to register your app in the Firebase console and in your `GoogleService-Info.plist`.